# Binary search as a generic algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search

I am upgrading my C++11 knowledge and repeating some essential algorithm. Here is binary search only in terms of iterators.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<typename t_iter>
t_iter binarySearch(t_iter begin, t_iter end, typename iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type q)
{
    typedef iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type t_elem;
    size_t len = end - begin;

    if (len < 2)
    {
        if (*begin == q)
        {
            return begin;
        }

        return end;
    }

    t_iter middleElem = begin + len / 2;

    if (*middleElem < q)
    {
        return binarySearch(middleElem, end, q);
    }

    return binarySearch(begin, middleElem, q);
}

int main()
{
    int tmp[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 35, 41, 42, 100};
    size_t len = sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]);
    vector<int> a(tmp, tmp + len);

    int q = 35;

    auto it = binarySearch(a.begin(), a.end(), q);

    cout << distance(a.begin(), it) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Everybody else has covered everything I wanted to say. **BUT** they all missed the error. Boo ha ha. After the first iteration this `return end;` is unlikely to be the actual `end` iterator (it is the end of the current range which has been subdivided many times). eg: finding `2` in `[1, 3, 4, 5]` will return the iterator for `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterators may not be random access iterators which means the length calculation and the advance by half won't compile.

For this there is the `distance` and `advance` functions available which use the random access if it is available but fall back to counting and repeated incrementing when it isn't.

You never use the `t_elem` type def.

In the recursion step both branches are equally likely and equally important, that is best signified and made more readable by using an `else` branch rather than letting it fall through.

you can also implement as a loop to minimize recursion overhead (micro-optimization admittedly because automatic tail-call optimization would do the same).

```
template<typename t_iter>
t_iter binarySearch(t_iter begin, t_iter end, typename iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type q)
{
    auto len = std::distance(begin, end);

    while(len>1)
    {
        t_iter middleElem = begin;
        std::advance(middleElem, len / 2);

        if (*middleElem < q)
        {
            begin = middleElem;
        }
        else
        {
            end = middleElem;
        }
        len = std::distance(begin, end);
    }

    if (*begin == q)
    {
        return begin;
    }
    return end;

}
```

Comment: You don't want to use binary_search with non-random iterators. So I suppose it is better to generate an error in that case: don't use distance and advance.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini depends if the slowdown is in the compare or the increment, binary searching a linked list (with increments and counting) of strings is still faster than linear searching

Comment: I think that it may happen that a user does not realize that its container is not random access and uses binary search erroneously. Instead the case where a user really needs a binary search with a non random iterator is very uncommon and we could require the user to wrap his non-random iterator with a fake random one (by using advance to implement operator+) before performing binary search.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed review! Ensuring that a random access iterator is passed would make sense IMHO, but I don't think there is a reasonable simple way to do this without concepts.

Comment: Ah and also the iterative solution is better of course :)

Comment: You probably don't want `return end;` as this has been altered from the original `end` value that was passed in.

Answer (score 5):

### Undefined behavior

Your code will dereference an end iterator if the range is empty at this location:

```
if (len < 2)
{
    if (*begin == q)
```

Because the range is empty, `len == 0` and `begin == end`. The `end` should never be dereferenced for comparison (even if it might be a valid iterator).

### Wrong difference type

The difference of two (random access) iterators results in a `std::ptrdiff_t` not `std::size_t`. The latter is unsigned while the former is a signed type!

### Don't `using namespace std;`

`using namespace std;` does more harm than good. Although programmers are lazy some `std::` more won't hurt you. If you really want to avoid typing `std::` multiple times then don't use `using namespace` but for example `using std::iterator_traits`. And make sure that these instances are as localized as possible (never outside of functions in header files).

### Compiler error

You are using a dependent name and should be using `typename` here:

```
typedef iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type t_elem;
```

And this `typedef` is not even used!

### C++11

The only C++11 feature I can spot in your code is one instance of `auto` on this line:

```
auto it = binarySearch(a.begin(), a.end(), q);
```

You have missed several opportunities to use C++11. E.g.:

```
int tmp[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 35, 41, 42, 100};
size_t len = sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]);
vector<int> a(tmp, tmp + len);
```

Why waste memory on `tmp` when you could have done the initialization shorter and more secure:

```
vector<int> a = {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 35, 41, 42, 100};
```

C++11 replaces `typedefs` by `using` declarations:

```
typedef typename iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type t_elem;
```

becomes

```
using t_elem = typename iterator_traits<t_iter>::value_type;
```

Even more conveniently this using syntax allows for templates and does not need the indirection via member types (thereby reducing the need for `typename`):

```
template <class Iterator>
using Value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

template<typename t_iter>
t_iter binarySearch(t_iter begin, t_iter end, Value_type<t_iter> q)
```

There is another location for usage of `auto` here:

```
t_iter middleElem = begin + len / 2;
```

### Naming

- `t_iter` is not a very good type name, the usual convention would be `iter_t`
- one character names like `q` are not very helpful as well. How about `wanted_value`
- `middleElem` breaks with the naming of `begin` and `end`, to me it sounds like this variable should store the value of the element pointed to by an iterator `middle` (which would IMHO be a more consistent name for this iterator)

Comment: Agreed with everything except the last point: This is just a simple example no real code.

Comment: @Nils: I have extended the list. There is no such thing as "no real code". Either it is code or it isn't. Having exceptions for "non real" code opens the door for letting this behavior creep into your daily practice ("nah this is just a quick hack, no real code") until it gets into production and trips you up there.

Comment: Yes I know VS2012 lacks of some support, but why using using instead of typedef? I do not se how this is better.

Comment: As I explained the `using` declaration is more powerful than a `typedef` (it can be templated and it works more like a function when used for template meta functions). I would recommend that you update your compiler to a more C++11 compliant one if you really want to learn and use C++11.

Comment: Nice review! I think you can do even better than the using statement: `decltype(*begin)`. I think it's easier to read and it works even for custom iterators that haven't defined a specialization of `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: @ruds: `decltype(*begin)` could not do what is intended (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15560972/760746). If you write a custom iterator you have to specialize `std::iterator_traits` anyway or your iterator won't be compatible with the stdlib's algorithms.

Comment: Interesting point about the proxy classes.